# DynamicData RegisterContext error using multiple edmx

Tags: entity-framework-4, global-asax, edmx

Before posting this I made sure to read all suggestion made from SO.

The application currently has two projects one for the web application and one for the Entity Frame work (version 4.0). We are trying a tool from RSSBus for the Quickbooks Provider [description here](http://www.rssbus.com/ado/quickbooks/)
Setting it up was easy enough. I prefixed QB on all the entities and generated the QB.tt file, no issues. Both edmx files are housed in the same project using a shared namespace (SMR.Model)

When I rebuilt the project to run it the global.asax.cs file threw an error:

```
DefaultModel.RegisterContext(typeof(SMR.Model.SMREntities),
new ContextConfiguration() { ScaffoldAllTables = true });
```

The error given was:

> The given key was not present in the dictionary.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: The given key was not present in the dictionary.
>
> Source Error: 
>   Line 36:         public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
>   Line 37:         {
>   Line 38:             DefaultModel.RegisterContext(typeof(SMR.Model.SMREntities),
>   Line 39:                 new ContextConfiguration() { ScaffoldAllTables = true });
>   Line 40:
>
> Source File: C:\all\src\smr\smr.pl.Web\Global.asax.cs    Line: 38
>
> Stack Trace: 
>   [KeyNotFoundException: The given key was not present in the dictionary.]
>      System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.get_Item(TKey key) +9624829
>      System.Web.DynamicData.ModelProviders.EFDataModelProvider..ctor(Object contextInstance, Func`1 contextFactory) +800
>      System.Web.DynamicData.ModelProviders.SchemaCreator.CreateDataModel(Object contextInstance, Func`1 contextFactory) +126
>      System.Web.DynamicData.MetaModel.RegisterContext(Func`1 contextFactory, ContextConfiguration configuration) +378
>      System.Web.DynamicData.MetaModel.RegisterContext(Type contextType, ContextConfiguration configuration) +88
>      smr.pl.Web.Global.RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes) in C:\all\src\smr\smr.pl.Web\Global.asax.cs:38
>      smr.pl.Web.Global.Application_Start(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\all\src\smr\smr.pl.Web\Global.asax.cs:91
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): The given key was not present in the dictionary.]
>      System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.EnsureAppStartCalledForIntegratedMode(HttpContext context, HttpApplication app) +9170941
>      System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +131
>      System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +194
>      System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +339
>      System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr appContext) +253
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): The given key was not present in the dictionary.]
>      System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +9090044
>      System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +97
>      System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +256

With so little to go on as to what could eb the problem I looked at the .config files to see if they were wrong and all checked out as ok.

```
<add name="SMREntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=SMR;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=XXX;MultipleActiveResultSets=True&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"/>
<add name="RSSQBEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model.QBOE.csdl|res://*/Model.QBOE.ssdl|res://*/Model.QBOE.msl;provider=System.Data.RSSBus.QuickBooks;provider connection string=&quot;Offline=False;Application Id=987654321;Connection Ticket=TGT-000-T_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx;Online Login=ohno&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Any thoughts as to what is causing the structure to fail like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out the "real" problem. I first seperated the two models into separate projects. The problem I was facing was the metadata was being integrated into the same assembly namespace. I resolved my issue by updating the res://*/ section

```
<add name="SMREntities" connectionString="metadata=res://SMR.Model/;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=SMR;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=XXX;MultipleActiveResultSets=True&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"/>
<add name="RSSQBEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://SMR.QBOE/Model.RSSQBOE.csdl|res://SMR.QBOE/Model.RSSQBOE.ssdl|res://SMR.QBOE/Model.RSSQBOE.msl;provider=System.Data.RSSBus.QuickBooks;provider connection string=&quot;Offline=False;Application Id=987654321;Connection Ticket=TGT-000-T_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx;Online Login=ohno&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

A Classic "the issue is not the issue".

Comment: You should accept this answer as well. It increases your chances of getting good answers for future questions, and keeps the whole SO community in a good state.